# How to set pointer speed?

Tags: kali-linux, mouse, settings

I have kali linux 2 installed. And I have a mouse of 8200 cpi. How can I set the minimal mouse pointer speed? If I set minimum in settings, it is still unusable. Also I tried:`xset m 0 0`, but still bad.
Is there any way to set speed, dnk, lower than 0?

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mouse_acceleration

Comment: What's the output from `xset q` both before and after you try `xset m 0 0`?  I'm wondering if `xset m 0 0` might not be interpreted in a useful way.  Does Kali Linux have `xinput`?

Answer (score 1):

Try playing with this command:

```
dconf-editor
```

Inside these schemas:

```
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.mouse
org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.touchpad
```

With these settings:

```
motion-acceleration
motion-threshold
```

Their values could be from `0 - 1.79e308`.

Comment: Even when I set it to zero. And if negative, I don't even get what happens. It is still unusable. Seems like I will faster get used to it then find the solution.(

Comment: Or... It is rather strange. But when I set it to 10000, it had become better.

Comment: @ДимаДолгополов Привет! Ok, so I suppose that the value ranges can exceed `10.0` I don't remember where I read it, but the most important is: works it for you? It seems to be a `1024 bits` number, so you can try even larger numbers up to 1.79e308 :D

Comment: Yep) But why does it work? Max number should have been about 100, I think, but still sensitivity changes when I choose between 10000 and 100000. And what is more interesting, sens on 10 is more than on 10000, BUT 100000 has bigger sensitivity then 10000 :D

Comment: I don't exactly why... And can't experiment with larger numbers than `10.0` .... : ( but it is interesting ....